# Assign color to select OPTION

Tags: jquery, css

If I want to change the color of one particular option label, can I do it with jQuery?
For example, can i have only RED option to appear in red color?

Let's say I have the following

```
<select class="mySelect">
   <option value="white">White</option>
   <option value="black">Black</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Couldn't I do something like:

```
$("#mySelect").val('red').addClass('redText');
```

Comment: Why jQuery? This can be done with CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`$('option[value="red"]').addClass('redText');`

`$("#mySelect").val('red').addClass('redText');` will select only the `<select>` tag and set the value property of it to 'red'. The `val()` method is a setter/getter.

Comment: Actually it would be great if the options are all the same -- black but if RED is selected it showed in RED. Would I do something like: $('.mySelect').change(function() {
   if ( $('.mySelect').val() == 'red' ) { $("#mySelect").val('red').addClass('redText'); }
  });

Comment: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXPsu/) might do almost what you want (it styles the whole `select` red instead of just one option). I would echo @karim79's comment from above; styling just the `option` tags is pretty finicky across browsers.

Comment: Hmm, isn't there a way to target FIRST option using DOM to apply RED to just the selected option? Perhaps that way it won't apply to entire list? It just seems there's gotta be a way with jQuery... Maybe something like: $('#mySelect option:selected').addClass('redText');

Comment: Something like this, but I'm afraid I'm missing something... http://jsfiddle.net/FXPsu/3/ because option:selected refers to the option in the list and not the selected value showing onload.

Comment: You're looking for the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to style the `option` tag directly. `$('.mySelect > option:selected').addClass('redText');` will add the class to the `option` tag, but different browsers style `option` tags differently. You'll have to play around with it to get it to work cross-browser. If possible, I would use something other than a `select` element. Otherwise I'd look for a plugin to iron out the cross-browser issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the 7th option in the select and light it up with whatever the interesting class is.

```
$('#myselect).find(" option:eq(7)").addClass("interesting_class");
```