# How to color text with multiple colors in option tag

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I have a drop down list in a form where I'm showing 2 values. I like the 2nd value to have another text color (light gray).
I've been searching how to do this, and apparently you need to use Java-script for this. Unfortunately I'm not very good with Java-script and everything I tried so far didn't work.

```
<select name="cities">
    <option value="1">London (England)</option>
    <option value="2">Sidney (Australia)</option>
    <option value="3">Amsterdam (Netherlands)</option>
</select>
```

I tried things like:

```
<option value="1">
    <span style="text-decoration:line-through">London</span>
    <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">(England)</span>
</option>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('country').style.color = '#FF0000';
</script>

<option value="1">London <span id='country' style='color:red'>(England)</span></option>
```

And although it works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/pzHqT/) it doesn't work on my site.

Another option that comes close is [Assign color to select OPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877234/assign-color-to-select-option)

Anyone know a simple bit of java-script code to make this possible?
Thank you

Comment: This question is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372476/how-to-write-text-with-multiple-colors-in-option-tag but that one was never fully answered.

Comment: Although the `option` supports a few styles, in order to apply vivid styles why not write your own html and script to generate custom select box?

Comment: Unfortunately there hasn't been a good answer given yet.
Anyone able to help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS. Like this

```
select option:nth-child(even) {
    color: green;
}

select option:nth-child(odd) {
    color: "#000";
}
```

Or just to change color of 2nd option

```
select option:nth-child(2) {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: color property works fine. What about other styles such as bold?

Comment: @Moogs try different color like green/gray.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
The solution I'm looking for however has 2 different colors on the same line. In my case display the city and country in two different colors (black and light gray).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a450ga14/4/)(this needs a lot of work to be put in)

You could create a custom Dropdown control as shown but there are a lot of things to be kept in mind and are to be handled such as to hide the dropdown on clicking anywhere outside it.

Just pasting the HTML for your reference

```
<div class="selected">London (England)</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div id="1" class="outer"><div class="first">London</div><div class="second"> (England)</div></div>
    <div id="2" class="outer"><div class="first">Sidney</div><div class="second"> (Australia)</div></div>
    <div id="3" class="outer"><div class="first">Amsterdam</div><div class="second"> (Netherlands)</div></div>
</div>
```